# How to replace %252C to hyphens from the URL via htaccess rule?

Tags: .htaccess, replace

How can I replace `%252C` with hyphens in a the URL using `.htaccess`?

Example URL:

```
http://example.com/sitename/New-York-Mills/New+York+Mills%252C+MN%252C+United+States/tamarind/New+york
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\%2[Cc](.*)$ /$1-$2
```

Or if you already have rewrite rules, stick with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%2[Cc](.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @user3156921 have you tried the other rule? If you already have rules the first one will not work, you need to use the rewrite rule and it must be **before** your other rules.